# Not sure whats wrong in the below Query of the problem "Biggest Single Number" from leetcoode

Tags: sql, mysql, count

A single number is a number that appeared only once in the MyNumbers table.

Write an SQL query to report the largest single number. If there is no single number, report null.

The query result format is in the following example.

Example 1:

```
Input: 
MyNumbers table:
+-----+
| num |
+-----+
| 8   |
| 8   |
| 3   |
| 3   |
| 1   |
| 4   |
| 5   |
| 6   |
+-----+
Output: 
+-----+
| num |
+-----+
| 6   |
+-----+
```

Explanation: The single numbers are 1, 4, 5, and 6.
Since 6 is the largest single number, we return it.

My Query :

```
select  ifnull(num,null) as num 
from MyNumbers 
group by num
having count(num)=1
order by num desc
limit 1;
```

Why the above query is not returning the null, if there no single numbers

I was expecting to display null for non single number test case,but its showing empty table

Comment: Your query returns no rows. Null refers to the value of a field in a row. Therefore your null-related code doesn’t apply as there is no row to apply it to

Comment: @NickW Correct me if i am wrong, is empty mean null right?

Comment: There’s a difference between a query returning no rows and a query returning rows and a field value in one of those rows being null. If the query returns no rows then there are no fields  - so you can’t say that a field value could be null or not

Comment: Below Query is working fine:  select ifnull((select  num 
from MyNumbers 
group by num
having count(num)=1
order by num desc
limit 1) ,null) as num
; but whats the differnece in this and the previous one

Answer (score 1):

You can't return a null value if your result set contains no rows since that still requires a row to be returned and a value to operate on.

If you want to return a NULL value in the event of no qualifying rows you could create a union of two sets:

```
with n as (
  select num 
  from t 
  group by num
  having count(*) = 1
  union all select null
)
select num
from n
order by num desc
limit 1;
```

You could also use a case expression to test the number of rows and return a null, this requires that at least some data exists

```
select case when Count(*)> 1 then null else num end Num
from t 
group by num
order by Count(*), num desc
limit 1;
```

Some [fiddle examples](https://dbfiddle.uk/DlgmpDEF)

Comment: I like the `union` but the sub select seems unnecessary and overly wordy

Comment: Sometimes 'overly' wordy can add clarity for someone learning SQL or not familiar with a concept, the optimzer will not be fooled.

Answer (score 0):

count(num) will return `0` for null values. This can be solved by using  `count(*)`:

```
select  ifnull(num,null) as num 
from MyNumbers 
group by num
having count(*)=1
order by num desc
limit 1
;
```

see [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/kji9BTba), for a step-by-step solution.

Comment: "If there is no single number, report null" you seem to have changed this into "if there is a null but no single number, report null ) .  `ifnull(num,null)` isn't this the same as just `num` ?

Comment: In my answer `ifnull(num,null)` is the same as just `num`, But in the question a values of `null` will never be returned because `count(null)` will always return 0, and "no records" will not return a `null` value.

Comment: Right, but your method only works if there *is* exactly one NULL value in the table if I'm not mistaken.  That's why the other answers `union` with a `null` query result.

Comment: Indeed the solution using `union` is better.  But I am, in this case, trying to make clear that there is a difference between `count(*)` and `count(num)`.

Answer (score 0):

> Write an SQL query to report the largest single number.

Okay, `group by num having count(*) = 1` is just fine for that.  This is the tricky part:

> If there is no single number, report null.

The `having` will filter out all rows that don't have a count of one.  So if there are no numbers with a count of one, there are 0 rows in the result set.  That's not the same as a result with one row of `null`.

An aside: beyond exercise, this is a stupid requirement.  It doesn't make sense to conflate `null` with an empty result set.  An empty result set is the correct way to express the lack of matching data.  Okay, this is just an exercise, after all.

[Here is my simple solution](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/264tKXAQGtRaAcjJzH1w8i/0).   I simply `union` the reults of the `select` on `MyNumbers` with a select of `null`.  Now there's a `null` in the result set, and if there's no other result in the result set, the `null` is the only one to come out of the limit.  If there is a number, that's returned instead.

```
select num from MyNumbers  num group by num having count(num) = 1 
union select null as num
order by num desc limit 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query returns no rows when it's nothing to return. As your original query returns at most a single scalar the simplest way is to make it an expression `select (<original scalar query>) as res` :

```
select (
    select num 
    from MyNumbers 
    group by num
    having count(num)=1
    order by num desc
    limit 1
    ) res
```